# How to add Closing tags in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I need your assistance with the logic to add the end tags. The structure i am looking at is . I tried with for-each or xsl:if or xsl:choose. The input XML is as below

```
   <SuperShipNotice>
   <Package packageType="P" packageLevel="1">
   <PackageNumber>PWN34332</PackageNumber>
   <ShipmentNumber>105909390</ShipmentNumber>
   <ShipmentLineNumber>1</ShipmentLineNumber>
   <PartNumber>1CH162-510</PartNumber>
   <Quantity>1000</Quantity>
   <SSCCNumber>00176364909402100165</SSCCNumber>
   </Package>
   <Package packageType="C" packageLevel="2">
   <PackageNumber>CWX612432660</PackageNumber>
   <ParentPackageNumber>PWN34332</ParentPackageNumber>
   <ShipmentNumber>105909390</ShipmentNumber>
   <ShipmentLineNumber>1</ShipmentLineNumber>
   <PartNumber>1CH162-510</PartNumber>
   <Quantity>25</Quantity>
   <SSCCNumber>00176364909402100165</SSCCNumber>
   </Package>
   <Package packageType="S" packageLevel="3">
   <PackageNumber>W1D2WNGL</PackageNumber>
   <ParentPackageNumber>CWX612432660</ParentPackageNumber>
   <ShipmentNumber>105909390</ShipmentNumber>
   <ShipmentLineNumber>1</ShipmentLineNumber>
   <PartNumber>1CH162-510</PartNumber>
   <Quantity>1</Quantity>
   <DateOfMfg>20131209</DateOfMfg>
   <COO>CN</COO>
   <SSCCNumber>00176364909402100165</SSCCNumber>
   </Package>
   <Package packageType="S" packageLevel="3">
      <PackageNumber>W1D2WNGL</PackageNumber>
      <ParentPackageNumber>CWX612432660</ParentPackageNumber>
      <ShipmentNumber>105909390</ShipmentNumber>
      <ShipmentLineNumber>1</ShipmentLineNumber>
      <PartNumber>1CH162-510</PartNumber>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <DateOfMfg>20131209</DateOfMfg>
      <COO>CN</COO>
      <SSCCNumber>00176364909402100165</SSCCNumber>
      </Package>
     </SuperShipNotice>
```

Comment: It'll be easier to get an answer if you also add the expected output and what you've already tried.

Comment: Honestly, what is the question? The sample is well-formed xml, so there are no closing tags to add. Your question itself suggests some kind of misunderstanding of xslt transforming from xml to xml: this technique operates on xml structures, so you typically do not add eg. closing tags in isolation ( it is feasible but isn't boilerplate application )

Comment: <PkgLevel1>
        <PackageNumber>PSI08294</PackageNumber>
          <PkgLevel2>
           <PkgLevel3>
            <PackageNumber>NA327KHR</PackageNumber>
             </PkgLevel3>
         </PkgLevel2>
  </PkgLevel1>

Comment: You should better add this to the question instead of as comment. Still a bit unclear as these `PackageNumber`s aren't in the input XML. Additional question: if you want this kind of nested output for the different `PkgLevel`s, why is the `PackageNumber` for `PkgLevel2` missing? Is it because it's the same for Level2 and Level3 and if so, will it always be the same for both and only  `PackageNumber`s for Level1 and Level3 are requested in the output?

Comment: The structure i mentioned in the comments section is what i am looking for. as u can see the closing tags for PkgLevel1 and PkgLevel2 are after PkgLevel3 closing tag. It is a miss from my side to add the PackageNumber under PkgLevel2 element

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can be of any use for you - following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:template match="SuperShipNotice">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//PackageNumber[parent::Package[@packageLevel='1']]" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="PackageNumber[parent::Package[@packageLevel='1']]">
    <xsl:variable name="packageNumber" select="." />
    <PkgLevel1>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//PackageNumber[parent::Package[@packageLevel='2'] and parent::Package/ParentPackageNumber = $packageNumber]" />
    </PkgLevel1>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="PackageNumber[parent::Package[@packageLevel='2']]">
    <xsl:variable name="packageNumber" select="." />
    <PkgLevel2>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//PackageNumber[parent::Package[@packageLevel='3'] and parent::Package/ParentPackageNumber = $packageNumber
and not(parent::Package/ParentPackageNumber = preceding::Package[@packageLevel='3']/ParentPackageNumber)]" />
    </PkgLevel2>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="PackageNumber[parent::Package[@packageLevel='3']]">
    <PkgLevel3>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </PkgLevel3>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

when applied to your input XML produces the output

```
<PkgLevel1>
  <PackageNumber>PWN34332</PackageNumber>
  <PkgLevel2>
    <PackageNumber>CWX612432660</PackageNumber>
    <PkgLevel3>
       <PackageNumber>W1D2WNGL</PackageNumber>
    </PkgLevel3>
  </PkgLevel2>
</PkgLevel1>
```

The first template matching `SuperShipNotice` applies templates to `PackageNumber`s of `Package`s with the `packageLevel` value `1`.
In the template matching those `Packagenumber`s templates are applied to all `PackageNumber`s with the `packageLevel` value `2` and the `ParentPackageNumber` of the current `PackageNumber`.
As there is a double entry for `Packages` with the `packageLevel` value `3`, the second `Package` with the same `ParentPackageNumber` is omitted:

```
select="//PackageNumber[parent::Package[@packageLevel='3'] 
        and parent::Package/ParentPackageNumber = $packageNumber 
        and not(parent::Package/ParentPackageNumber = preceding::Package[@packageLevel='3']/ParentPackageNumber)]"
```

In case you can adjust this to fit further requirements, you can use the saved [Demo](http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzQz)